# Why does this function return the correct height of a binary tree?

Tags: kotlin, tree, binary

I am trying to unravel this recursive function, but I haven't been able to find out why it returns the value 3:

1. Here's the tree:

```
         

         1 (2)
        / \
   (1) 3   9 (-1) 
      / \
(-1) 4   5 (0)
        /
       6 (-1)
```

Here's the function to find the height:

```
fun height(node: BinaryNode<T>? = this): Int {
    return node?.let { 
        1 + max(height(node.leftChild), height(node.rightChild)) 
    } ?: -1
}
```

When I traced the function back to the place when the very first node 1 was called, you can see that the value is 2. But I print the value and it's always 3. Here's the call:

```
println(tree.height())
```

where does this extra 1 sneek in?

Answer (score 0):

For a leaf node, `4`, `6` or `9` in your example, it returns

```
node?.let {
    1 + max(height(null), height(null))
} ?: -1
```

When `node` is `null`, the block of `let` won't be executed, thus the value returned is -1.

So

```
node?.let {
    1 + max(-1, -1)
} ?: -1
```

is `0`.

Please trace your code to understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now. All the leaves are 0, not -1 as I thought.